# Did Shaykh Ibn Taymiyyah Believe That Allah Looks Like a Beardless Man?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Ibn Taimiyah believe that Allah (swt) is like a beardless man? Is this hadith authentic?

We read in al-Tasis fi al-rad ala Asas al-Taqdis, Volume 3 page 214:
فيتضح أنها رؤية عين كما في الحديث الصحيح المرفوع عن قتادة عن عكرمة عن ابن عباس قال قال رسول الله رأيت ربي في صورة أمرد له وفرة جعد قطط في روضة خضراء

We conclude that it was eyesight as it is in the Sahih narration from Qutada from Ikrama from Ibn Abbas said that the Prophet said : ‘I saw my God in image of beardless (man), with long curly hair in a green garden’

Comment: May I ask about your source that this was Ibn Taimiyah's view? It is not the actual book you mentioned, because the section you referred to is the fourth out of several sections that ibn Taimiyah is quoting from others to refute. It is not his view.

Comment: Or are you asking about the authenticity of the hadith of ibn 'Abbas? Because ibn Taimiyah concluded that it was fabricated in "Dar' Ta'arud Al Naql as Al 'Aql", as did Al Qadi Abu Ya'ala and others.